# Best way to draw line between fix CGPoint and moving UIView object's center point

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, line, drawrect

I have a UIView subclass object that animates and therefore changes its position over time as a subview in my UIViewController's view. Actually my moving UIView subclass is just an image of a ball and it's moving as if it was hanging down from my devices screens top border. But to be a real pendulum I'd like to also draw a line between my ball and the CGPoint it hangs down from on top of my screen.

My idea was to just draw a line every time the UIView changes its position. But as the moving is done within an iOS API (I'm just calling something like `[myBallView swing]`) I can't do this at the same place the movement is happening. I'm actually not animating the view myself.

The only solution I have in my mind to solve my issue is pretty bad: subclassing UIView, adding it as a superview to my moving UIView and adding a line every time `drawRect` is called. But I'm not even sure `drawRect` is going to be called there. Either way, there must be a better solution for this.

Does anyone know a good solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Making a custom subclass of UIView as the superview is reasonable.

However, rather than drawing the line yourself, I would suggest implementing +layerClass in your custom view, and making the backing layer a CAShapeLayer.

Then you can create a CGPath in the view's shape layer that is a line, and manipulate the start and end points of the line when your other view's center moves. Shape layers are designed to draw as part of the screen update process, and you could even make the change animate by changing the endpoints of the path with a CABasicAnimation.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on how you would process the updates when the view's center moves? Is there a method that needs to be overridden in the +layerClass that will automatically be called upon animation?